# React.JS Navigating to hash route does not update view

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to React and I am working through a course on Pluralsight. The course has us implementing a simply route.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var Child;

        switch (this.props.route) {
            case 'about':
                Child = About;
                break;
            default:
                Child = Home;
                break;
        }

        return ( 
            <div>
                <Child />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function render(){
    var route = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    ReactDOM.render( <App route={route} /> , document.getElementById('app') );
}

window.addEventListener( 'hashChange', render );
render();
```

So, when I start up the app, the home page displays as it should. Yet, if I go to the address bar and type in http://localhost:3456/#about, the browser window does not refresh. I have to manually refresh the browser in order to see the about page. But if I go back and remove the "#about" the home page displays properly.

I am using windows 10 and I have tried this on both Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashchange` is not camel case and the event is not standardized across browsers

use this function to make it work across browsers

```
function handleHashChange(callback) {
  if (!('onhashchange' in window)) {
    var oldHref = location.href;
    setInterval(function() {
      var newHref = location.href;

      if (oldHref !== newHref) {
        var _oldHref = oldHref;
        oldHref = newHref;
        callback.call(window, {
          'type': 'hashchange',
          'newURL': newHref,
          'oldURL': _oldHref
        });
      }
    }, 100);
  } else if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", callback, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onhashchange", callback);    
  } 
}
```

Comment: were you the one who answered that hashchange was not camel cased? Because that worked.

Comment: yes. i even went ahead to give u a cross browser solution